# Handling onItemClick event in a searchable ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I was wondering how I can fix the problem I'm currently having. Let me explain it:
I created a ListView with some strings. I used an onItemClick event which handles my click when I click on a certain item in the ListView. When I click Cocktails it'll open the cocktails page, when I click desserts, it'll open the desserts page. I used the position of the string in the array for this. (so position 0 = cocktails and position 1 = desserts, and so on..)

But the problem appears when I use the search function. Because when I search for 'd' the first item in the list will be desserts and when I click it it will open up cocktails, because I coded the 0th position to open up the cocktails page.

Is there a way for me to be able to not use position in the list, but refer the click to a string.
Something like: if ... == "cocktails" {Intent i = new Intent(Main.java, Cocktails.java)}...
This way I'm capable of hardcoding every string in the array to a certain page.

Is this possible? If so, could you please help me? Thanks!

My current code is:

```
public class Aperitiefhapjes extends Activity {

    private ListView lv; // List view
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; // Listview Adapter
    EditText inputSearch; // Search EditText
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList; // ArrayList for Listview

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aperitiefhapjes);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"cocktails","desserts"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_aperitiefhapjes);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.searchlist_item, R.id.searchlist_naam, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // Enabling Search Filter
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Aperitiefhapjes.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        registerClickCallback();
    }

    public void registerClickCallback()
    {
        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_aperitiefhapjes);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                //0 = cocktails
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Aperitiefhapjes.this, Cocktails.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }      
                //1 = desserts
                if(position == 1)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Aperitiefhapjes.this, Desserts.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the problem will have to be fixed in the registerClickCallback-method.

Comment: onItemClick gives you a View, from which you can find out which item has been clicked.

Comment: @Christine beat me to it. It's exactly why 'click' listeners provide the `View` as a parameter.

Comment: I would typically have a custom adapter extending Baseadapter, then you can add a tag to the view. Or you can just use the view id, or inspect the contents of the textview it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id)
 {
     String data=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
     // compare data and set your intents accordingly.


 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a custom array adapter to do similar stuff to this in the past.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
}
```

It's possible to tag a view with a 'view holder' class. I won't post lots of code, but just something to give you the basic idea. There are resources and examples available for you to see more involved details.

You'll declare an inner ViewHolder class to encapsulate other data associated with the listview item.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView itemNumber;
    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}
```

'Tag' the view like this

```
view.setTag(viewHolder);
```

and getting the tag data is done like this

```
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
```